# why is my drop-down box not populated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm sorry for the onslaught of remedial questions but I've been staring at this one for over an hour and it seems to match other examples in my code. My drop down box is not being populated as I expect it to be.

here is the entirety of my view:

```
<%= form_for :distro, :url => update_multiple_admin_distributions_workflows_path, :html => { :method => :put } do |f| %>
    <ul>
      <% for distribution in @distros %>
          <li>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "distribution_ids[]", distribution.id %>
            <%=h distribution.type %>
          </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map { |d| [d.status, d.status] }), :include_blank => true %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the rails console I get this:

```
>> Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map {|d| [d.status, d.status]}
[["delivered", "delivered"], ["follow up", "follow up"]]
  Distribution Load (0.5ms)  SELECT status FROM "distributions" GROUP BY status ORDER BY status
```

which seems to be the list I'm looking for.

Update:

I modified the select helper line and added `:distro` and started getting this error:

undefined method `merge' for "\n":ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer

some quick googling suggested i remove the `f.` part from the f.select. This however caused the dropdown box to shrink in width and remained blank.

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo when you pasted this code into Stackoverflow, but looks like you are missing a space on this line: `<%= h distribution.type %>` (before the `h`).

Comment: thanks for catching that but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Looks like you don't need the `options_for_select`, just feed in the `Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map {|d| [d.status, d.status]}` as an argument without the method call to `options_for_select`.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `options_for_select(` part (and the final parenthesis).

```
Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map { |d| [d.status, d.status] }
```

should provide all you need.

**Edit (re comment)**

`:distro` is in the `form_for`, the `f.select` adds it automagically.

```
<%= f.select :status, Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map { |d| [d.status, d.status] }, :include_blank => "-- Select One --" %>
```

Comment: this gives me: `Symbol as array index`

Comment: `<%= f.select :distro, :status, Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map { |d| [d.status, d.status] }, :include_blank => "-- Select One --" %>`